# React multiple pages using react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I m trying to make multiple react pages but react doesn't show any of the new pages . I think my code is correct , I am using `npm install react-router-dom@6`
and this is my code :
Index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
        <Route path="pricing" element={<Pricing />} />
        <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

in the Navbar.jsx :

```
<Link to="/pricing">Pricing</Link>
<Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
```

and for example Pricing.js :

```
        <div className='Pricing'>
            <Navbar />
        </div>
```

Any idea how to fix this ? where I have missed it exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are missing `/` on some path. Second, the first Route will catch all of them, because all of them start with `/`. To avoid that, you need the keyword `exact`, like so:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<App />} />
        <Route exact path="/pricing" element={<Pricing />} />
        <Route exact path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: I tried this solution but the problem is the same !

Comment: You had some  other typo problem, please take my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

**/** is missing in your code and also use **exact** property to match exact URL.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" exact element={<App />}>
        <Route path="/pricing" exact element={<Pricing />} />
        <Route path="/contact" exact element={<Contact />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```